# Redundancy from grammar

Tags: syntax

Consider the following sentence:

The pretty dog told the story the story.

There is obviously some redundancy in the 'whom' of telling and the 'what' of telling.

We can consider questions derived from this:

"What did the pretty dog tell the story?"

It seems like answering "the story," unless said with a kind of blankness, is a bit redundant. Is this phenomena well-known or studied?

Comment: Your example doesn't make sense... what does it mean to talk to a story??

Comment: Yes, and it's not clear what phenomenon you're talking about. The situation where two NPs in a clause have the same form?

Comment: To the first comment -- are you not familiar with the basics of Chomsky? Is the phrase "colorless green ideas... etc" unfamiliar? I think you will see that syntax and semantics are evaluated secondly.

Comment: To the second, one way of saying it is that if I simply reply "The pretty dog told the story." it is ambiguous as to whether I have more to say or I am finished. In writing it doesn't seem that way as much because one reads the sentence as a whole but in constructing these sentences vocally and listening to them this effect is present I think.

Comment: @user48801: "The basics of Chomsky" are not Divine Law. Many of C's presuppositions and hypotheses have been shown to be false and abandoned. Moreover, I'm not aware that Chomsky ever hypothesized that selectional restrictions on grammatical relations don't exist. They do; and one of them says that the indirect object of _tell_ must be a sentient being, or something else metaphorized as a sentient being. Anything else is ungrammatical. Like your first example.

Comment: @user48801 if you want to ask about syntactically valid but semantically meaningless and overall ungrammatical sentences then you should explicitly say so. I still don't know what you're trying to ask. How these sentences would work if they were ungrammatical even though they aren't?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you choose such a bad example? Talking to a story does not mean
much, and thus distracts from what you are trying to say. Why not use
*give* or *feed*, as in "he fed the animal the animal", which may be
ambiguous, but can make (double) sense, as we do not know what animals
in the context are being referred to, and there must be at least two.

Another point is that I do not see any redundancy. Redundancy implies
that the same information is given twice, possibly in different of
indirect ways. This is not the case here since the two occurences of
"the animal" correspond to NP clauses that have different roles, which
shows when you exchange them, when non identical, as in

```
    he gave the snake the mouse

    he gave the mouse to the snake
```

Of course "he gave the animal to the animal" is as ambiguous as "he
gave the animal the animal", short of semantic disambiguation (few mice have eaten live snakes).

Comment: So you think this is a question at the interface of syntax and pragmatics?

Comment: @user48801 Well, it does not seem to me to be a problem at all from a syntactic
point of view (depending possibly on what you consider syntactic - see
jlawler's comment), because these verbs will not allow commuting
freely direct and indirect object without a syntactic marker
("to"). The problem with "he gave the animal the animal" is that there
is a double anaphora which is so clearly ambiguous at first, that
people would most likely avoid it, except possibly in jest. For me
this is clearly beyond syntax, past the interface. But I am no expert
on where syntax stops.

Comment: @user48801: There is no interface between syntax and semantics; "the fetish for keeping syntax and semantics separate", as [Jim McCawley called it](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/McCawley-Lg.pdf), is deeply non-biological. There is no more an "interface" between syntax and semantics than there is between your flesh and your blood; each influences the other profoundly, at practically every level. And any theory that can't acknowledge this basic fact is more a distraction than a help.

Comment: @jlawler I should not have indulged the OP by mentionning "interface". It is
the kind of consideration I usually simply try to avoid. For me syntax
is often simply what will let colorless green ideas sleep furiously
(they do need rest). Or a convenience to specify how I limit my field
of discourse about linguistic structures. I would push anaphora more
on the semantic side. But it can naturally be also seen as a
sentence/discourse structuring device, hence part of syntax. Please
... Anyway, I do not see that the OP has identified any kind of
unusual linguistic phenomenon.

Comment: @jlawler I should add that one of my main interest in NLP is
ambiguity. One nice advantage of working with ambiguity is that it
allows postponing some of the influence of semantics on syntax, and helps
separating issues. It is much a technical device to organize
knowledge, that I feel similar in spirit to *continuation passing*
techniques used in programming. There is of course nothing biological
about it, afaik.

Comment: But every written sentence is multiply ambiguous syntactically, as Abney has demonstated. Dealing with ambiguity in NLP is like getting wet when you're fishing at sea.

Comment: @jlawler I may have been unclear.  I am talking of computational linguistics,
which may not be the major focus here.  The point is to work with
syntax (whatever it is) efficiently without attempting to resolve (often heavy)
ambiguities prematurely, which has often been done in the past.

Comment: Fair enough. That's almost always a matter of pragmatics or frame boundaries, and not syntax. Which is why statistical NLP gets such good results.